# Eavesdrop activities by government

Tags: privacy, anonymity, information-gathering

My friends country is fastly moving to Dictatorship. Currently, I am not in that country but when I try to talk to my friends, they are afraid of talking to me via Whatsapp or Skype because without any logical reason, people are sent to prisons and they are afraid that the (written or verbal) conversations are eavesdropped by the government.

When it comes to my question, is it so easy for a country to eavesdrop the conversations on internet (all the internet service providers in the country are under their control), or is it just a conspiracy theory to terrify the people?

Comment: In the state I live in there is [an official eavesdropping system which ISPs are required to deploy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SORM). It presumably sends all the traffic to FSB. I don't know how do they deal with such huge amounts of data, but this stuff exists since early 199x. You should also remember PRC's Great Firewall empowered with AI and forward connection. If your friend's state has little internet users, this can probably be a piece o' cake.

Comment: Ok but the whatsapp claims that the conversations are encrypted, even if the ISPs channel their traffic to a central, do they not get an encrypted data?

Comment: In my country mobile phones accounts bound to accs of such "secure" and "private" messengers are used to get access in some cases. And remember that business is business and that incooperating will cost business a lot of money. If law enforcement said "give me everything of that user you have" the business would complain. Read the ToS carefully. For example a lot of messengers (Google, FB, etc...) are required by law to move their datacenters into Russia. And mass media speculated that the aggreement about that have already been signed.

Comment: Don't say you have just learned that.

Comment: I knew it but each day, this idea goes deeper and deeper.

Comment: i wrote a web-based E2E chat for just such a scenario, safer than installed apps: https://nadachat.com/

Comment: @dandavis Very interesting project. I looked at it and I will use it. Thank you for your share and creating such a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one bullet proof way to protect from sniffing which doesn't involve trust in other authorities, it is **end-to-end encryption**. In short this means that the encryption and the decryption must be done client side, on the device of the sender/recipient.

There are services which claim to implement such end-to-end encryption, [WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/) for example adopted the protocol of Signal, a secure messenger with a good reputation, [others did as well](https://whispersystems.org/blog/). If we can trust in their implementation, you get a safe communication, without the possibility to eaves-drop, even if enforced. What you cannot hide though, are the contacts you are communicating with.

So no it is not a conspiracy theory, most communication *is* observed at this very moment. If my live would depend on it, I would setup an email client with client-to-client encryption. The problem is that your contact must do the same, or you can *trust* in services that offer this kind of encryption.

Comment: Does the security of the **end-to-end encryption** apply to the oral communications or just only for written ones?

Comment: @AdInfinitum - Both can be implemented with end-to-end encryption, this is what [Signal](https://whispersystems.org/) does. Both communications must be handled separately.

Comment: There is no bulletproof solution. For example your phone or PC can be infected.

Comment: And remember that in order to exchange keys you have to visit person, not to exchange the keys over Internet or whatsapp.

Comment: @KOLANICH - Yes and the contact can be threatened by other means to open the inbox, this is not a thing, a software can protect from of course.

Comment: Note that stackoverflow itself does NOT appear to require end to end encryption.

Comment: @AdInfinitum It applies to both, but it's difficult to carry out with oral communication. There's a fundamental conflict between real-time voice compression and confidentiality: voice compression and real-time transmission reveals the precise rhythm of speech, and that can be enough to reconstruct words. Additionally, keep in mind that end-to-end compression does not hide who is communicating with whom (popularly known as “metadata“ these days), and this can be the most important thing in government eavesdropping.

Answer (score 1):

Their government can use both. An overt psychological operation may say "we are listening, do not say anything bad about us or you will be arrested" is certainly scary.  If that can be followed up with actual physical arrests of public opposition figures, people know the government is not lying about arrests.  But the chance of being arrested may seem remote to someone who doesn't publicly speak out.  It won't stop you from complaining about the government privately.

The real terror comes from the 'disappeared'.  Virtually every human on earth has something they don't like about their rulers, and has at some time discussed it with their friends.  If someone vanishes, you don't know if that was because of a political conversation or not, but everyone suspects it.  That's the covert psychological operation, and is the truly terrifying aspect.

Can these governments break into private conversations?  We absolutely know they can see some of them.  Take a look at the history of The Hacking Team.  They were an Italian 'security' company that provided large-scale internet eavesdropping tools to many governments around the world  Their systems were hacked a couple of years ago, and sensitive data was revealed about who their customers were, including some brutally repressive regimes.  What we don't know is the security of current apps, or if they're targeting computers so that everything is exposed.  Is WhatsApp safe?  Is Silent Circle safe?   Even if you do everything right and never get infected by government sponsored malware, are you safe from traffic analysis?  Does the fact that you connect to a WhatsApp server automatically make you a suspect in a paranoid government's eyes?

Also take a look at the NSA's ANT catalog, and some of the leaked Snowden documents.  These give a picture of how the NSA intercepts and hacks into systems, and may suggest ways to avoid being attacked.  The NSA is pretty good at this stuff; they're probably far better at it than The Hacking Team ever was.  But they have a different focus: stealth and info gathering.  A repressive government may be only interested in deterrence, and won't care if you know that you're being snooped upon.

Broader advice on ways to avoid government surveillance is beyond the scope of your question, but there are many different resources out there.  The hard problem is knowing which advice is good advice, which advice is useless, and which advice is actually harmful.  And when arrests and disappearances are on the line, extreme caution must be exercised.  Even visiting such a web site or searching the web for "how to avoid government surveillance" could be used against someone.

Comment: You are totally right. In the past two months, 200.000 people are sacked from their jobs and more than 100.000 people are sent to the prison with no reason but a critic. Of course, they do not say the reason is a critism. They built a so-called terrorist organization and if you say something that they do not like, they say you serve this terrorist organization with your comments, e-mails, or articles etc. The history repeats itself and always the same theather is played but it works.